# Using regex to capture dialogue of a character in Shakespeare

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use regex to capture Shakespeare dialogue to practice using regex for text matching. For instance, I want to capture all the text spoken by a character called `CALIBAN` in this particular scene:

```
  PROSPERO. Thou most lying slave,
    Whom stripes may move, not kindness! I have us'd thee,
    Filth as thou art, with human care, and lodg'd thee
    In mine own cell, till thou didst seek to violate
    The honour of my child.

  CALIBAN. O ho, O ho! Would't had been done.
    Thou didst prevent me. I had peopl'd else
    This isle with Calibans.

  PROSPERO. Thou most lying slave,
    Whom stripes may move, not kindness! I have us'd thee,
    Filth as thou art, with human care, and lodg'd thee
    In mine own cell, till thou didst seek to violate
    The honour of my child.

  CALIBAN. O ho, O ho! Would't had been done.
    Thou didst prevent me. I had peopl'd else
    This isle with Calibans.
```

I'd like to capture

```
O ho, O ho! Would't had been done.
        Thou didst prevent me. I had peopl'd else
        This isle with Calibans.
```

How would I use regex to accomplish this? I tried this particular regex:

```
(?<=\n  CALIBAN\. )[A-Za-z ',\.\n\!-]+(?=\n  PROSPERO\. |$)
```

**Note:** in the actual text, there's always 2 white space characters, and then the new character's name. Each line has a carriage return at the end of it. 
My regex looks for `CALIBAN.` to start, then matches some text, and ensures that it must end with `PROSPERO.`. However, when I plug this into regexp.com, I have my entire text matched:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with lazy quantifier:

```
(?<=\n  CALIBAN\. )[A-Za-z\s',.!-]+?(?=\n  PROSPERO\. |$)
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRwezr/2)

In PHP use:

```
$re = '/(?<=\n  CALIBAN\. )[A-Za-z\s\',.!-]+?(?=\n  PROSPERO\. |$)/';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the result
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: It did! However, could you explain to me why the lazy quantifier was needed here? Like why was the original regex matching the entire expression?

Comment: If you keep greedy quantifier then match will be longest so it will match string before last  `\nPROSPERO\.`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following regex:

`CALIBAN. ((.*\n    .*)*)`

The first capture group (group 1) will match the text spoken by Caliban without including his name. Based upon the provided example, this regex should work.